# i can not upload video in background with delayed_job on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ffmpeg, delayed-job

I used paperclip background process with delay jobs with ffmpeg.

In paperclip processors folder i have ffmpeg.rb file also.

my model

```
class product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :video, :styles => {
    :mp4video => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'mp4', :convert_options => {:output => {:ar => 44100}} },
    :webmvideo =>{ :geometry => "1024x576", :format => 'webm', :convert_options => {:output => {:ar => 44100}} },
    :oggvideo => { :geometry => "1024x576", :format => 'ogg', :convert_options => {:output => {:ar => 44100}} },
    :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }
  },
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml",
  :processors => [:transcoder]

  process_in_background :video

end
```

Comment: what exactly a error. check your browser console as well as server console.

Comment: What was your delayed job last error?